# Calling a Fortran program within another Fortran program in Fortran 77

Tags: structure, fortran77

Say I have two programs: solve.f and plot.f . The solve program solves an equation and prints the data to a file. The plot routine reads that data and plots it. Is there a way that I can call the plot.f file in the solve.f file?

I've tried compiling the plot program (the file was named plot) and tried calling it using "call plot" but that did not work. I looked through the documentation and have not been able to find anything related to this issue.

The only alternative I can think of is to combine the two programs into one.

Comment: You can certainly call one program from another. But wouldn't it be easy to compile the code into one program and avoid all that file I/O?

Comment: I assume we are keeping the files separate to avoid very large files since the solve.f program is over 2000 lines long.

Comment: That's not that long. What's more a program can, and usually is, built from many source files. Why are you using file I/O to pass the info?

Comment: That's the way the program was structured before I began working on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I have completely misunderstood your question, can't you use the `SYSTEM()` function to execute `plot.f` (well, its compiled executable really) from `solve.f`?

Documentation is [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/SYSTEM.html).